# How to pass PHP value to JS. under CI

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter framework, my problem is I can't pass the right value from php to js. This code is for availability check from user input to database.

here is my controller

```
class Ajax extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->output->set_output("This is an AJAX endpoint!");
    }

    function activityCode_availability()
    {
        $activityCode = trim($this->input->post("activityCode"));
        $activityCode = mysql_escape_string($activityCode);

        $msg = $this->Activity_model->check_activityCode($activityCode);


        if($msg == 1)
        {
            $a= '<font color="#cc0000"><b>'.$activityCode.'</b> is already in use.</font>';
            return $a;
        }
        else
        {
            $b = 'OK';
            return $b;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my view

```
<?php
 $activityCode = array(
          'name'    => 'activityCode',
          'id'      => 'activityCode'
        );

 echo form_input($activityCode);
?>
<span id="availability_status"></span>
```

Here is my model

```
 function check_activityCode($activityCode)
 {  
      $query = $this->db->query("SELECT activityCode
            FROM ami_activity
            WHERE activityCode = '$activityCode'");

       return $query->num_rows();
 }
```

Here is my Javascript

```
(document).ready(function(){
   $('#activityCode').change(activity_check);
 });


 function activity_check()
 {
   var activityCode = $('#activityCode').val();
   var msgbox = $("#availability_status");

   if(activityCode.length > 2)
   {
       $("#availability_status").html('<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>img/loader.gif">&nbsp;Checking availability.');

       $.ajax({ 
          type: "POST", 
          url: "/index.php/ajax/activityCode_availability", 
          data: "activityCode="+ activityCode, 
          success: function(msg){ 
            $("#availability_status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request){ 
                if(msg == 'OK')
                { 
                    $("#activityCode").removeClass("red"); // remove red color
                    $("#activityCode").addClass("green"); // add green color
                    msgbox.html('<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>img/green_check.gif"> <font color="Green"> Available </font>');
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    $("#activityCode").removeClass("green"); // remove green color
                    $("#activityCode").addClass("red"); // add red  color
                    msgbox.html(msg);
                } 
            });
        } 
    }); 

}
else
{
    $("#activityCode").addClass("red"); // add red color
    $("#availability_status").html('<font color="#cc0000">Enter valid User Name</font>');
}
}
```

Any idea is very much appreciated. thanks in advanced.

Thanks,

Jams

Comment: sorry, but that's a whole lot of code. What's the problem with it? You can pass variables from PHP to javascript by echoing out a js-variable with a value from PHP.

Comment: You're using mysql_escape_string both where's not needed, and in the deprecated way: you should use mysql_real_escape_string, if any. Which is unnecessary if you call $this->db->escape() or use Active Record.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for that info Mr. Damien.. I'm sorry, this is my firstime I used CI. Anyway thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You should echo the $a/$b variables not return them. Currently the ajax request doesn't have any output.
You can use Firebug for Firefox or the Inspector Console in webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari) to see the actual response you're getting from the ajax request.

Comment: Yeah, I've done that. echoing $a and $b this is my first code but it doesn't worked so I try returning it but its the same error. I can't pass the value from php to my js. I'm sorry this is my firstime using CI. thanks @zbrox

Comment: I've copied your code in a test CI installation locally. I've faced only two problems with running this - 1) as I mentioned you should echo the ajax returns and not return them because you're not handling the response to some other PHP code, but you're outputting it to the ajax request and 2)there was a missing dollar sign in front of (document).ready but I guess that this is just a typo when pasting the code here.
Apart from that everything seems to work. Are you debugging this with Firebug for example? Do you see that the ajax request is being sent for sure?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your help, it is working right now. I figure out my error using firebug. There are two errors on my code 1 in my JS and 1 in my MySQL syntax

here are my errors

```
1.) url: "/index.php/ajax/activityCode_availability"
2.) on my model I included single quote on my condition
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT activityCode
        FROM survey_activity
        WHERE activityCode = '$activityCode'");
```

here are my solutions

```
1.) url: "my_folder/index.php/ajax/activityCode_availability"
2.) on my model I removed the single quote on my query condition
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT activityCode
        FROM survey_activity
        WHERE activityCode = $activityCode");
```

My ajax request is sending properly but in different url. it is sending on localhost/index.php/activityCode_availability instead of localhost/my_folder/index.php/activityCode_availability so it is sending on the default page of my localhost server. And also I implemented echoing $a and $b instead of returning it. Thanks to your advice. :)

Thanks,

Jams